# $\ln(xe^{-x}+e^{-x})=\ln(x+1)-x$?

Tags: logarithms

Actually it is small part of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2186218/limit-without-lh%C3%B4pitale-rule-or-infinity-serieses#2186218) . I am unable to understand how $\ln(xe^{-x}+e^{-x})=\ln(x+1)-x$ ? Please give only hint.

Comment: Hint:  $\ln(ab)=\ln(a)+\ln(b)$ and $\ln(e^{-x})=-x$.

Comment: try looking at the common factor and then use the properties of the logarithm

Comment: $\ln(xe^{-x}+e^{-x})=\ln\bigl((x+1) e^{-x}\bigr)=\ln(x+1)+\ln (e^{-x})$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we have $$\ln(x+1)-x=\ln(x+1)-\ln(e^x)=\ln\left(\frac{x+1}{e^x}\right)=\ln(xe^{-x}+e^{-x})$$

Comment: $\log a - \log b =\log \dfrac ab \neq \dfrac{\log a}{b}$

Comment: you are right, it was a typo,sorry thank you for the hint